# how to convert 123456,123456,B-CAT to '123456','123456','B-CAT' in python

Tags: python-2.7

By using this query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ProductID) FROM blog_txstock
WHERE LastUpdateOn BETWEEN  ('2016-05-01 00:00:00') AND ('2016-05-09 00:00:00');
```

I am getting the result like

```
123456,123456,B-CAT
```

but i want to convert that result in to

```
'123456','123456','B-CAT'
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the outer quotes:

```
>>> s = '123456,123456,B-CAT'
>>> ",".join("'{0}'".format(i) for i in s.split(','))
"'123456','123456','B-CAT'"
```

In case you are wondering why its showing with an extra `" "` that's just the way its represented, if you save the resulting value and print it, you will get the result you want.

```
>>> r = ",".join("'{0}'".format(i) for i in s.split(','))
>>> print(r)
'123456','123456','B-CAT'
```